# Use static type instead of variable

Tags: c#

Is there any way to tell the compiler to use a static type instead of a variable when your project doesn't use namespaces?

For instance, I have a class called User with various static and non-static methods. Let's say one of the static methods is called `GetUser()`.

I'm trying to call that `User.GetUser()` method from a method that also has a variable in scope (inherited from base class) called User. However, the compiler complains saying that it can't find `User.GetUser()` because it thinks I'm referring to the User variable that's in scope.

If this project used namespaces, I could just do `ns1.User.GetUser()`, but that's not feasible in this case. Is there a way that I can tell the compiler that I'm referring to the `User` type instead of the `User` variable?

Comment: ... Can you rename your variable?  I generally recommend against using capitalized variable names.  This is why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
global::User.GetUser()
```

Or a using directive to alias the type:

```
using UserType = User;

...

UserType.GetUser();
```

I'd strongly encourage you to use namespaces though :)

Answer (score 6):

Can you write `global::User.GetUser()`?

See [global](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `global::User.GetUser()`.
2. Use an alias: `using UserClass = User;`
3. Rename the Variable.
4. Rename the type.
5. Reduce the scope of the variable such that it's no longer in scope where you're using it.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use an alias for your static class. In your `using` directives, you can add:

```
using StaticUser = User;
```

Then there would be no more ambiguity.