# What is the danger of not using C# namespaces?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have proved to myself that the namespace is not required to compile and run an application.  However, what are the dangers and pitfalls of not using a namespace?  It creates layers that I am trying to avoid.

I know you're screaming but what about agile and abstraction so that 20 layers of abstraction exist between the code and the object.  I'm not asking if it violates this or that flavor of the month agile thing.  Just what, if any, real world issues come about by not using a namespace?

Edit:

Creating a stand alone class dll so no conflicts within the class project.  Trying to avoid when I include it in other projects having to use full qualified name.  myNamespace.myClass MyClass = new myNamespace.myClass();

From the comments it appears that naming conflicts are the biggest problem.

Guess I should use a using statement and buck up...

Comment: Namespaces do not add any "layer of abstraction."  They are glorified name prefixes for types, with compile-time support for importing all of the members of a given namespace into the local scope (`using`).  There is no runtime performance penalty for using namespaces.  In other words, there is little difference between `namespace Foo { class Bar { } }` and `class Foo_Bar { }` except that other code gets the ability to `using Foo;` for the convenience of the developer.

Comment: What I mean by "it creates layers" is that when I create the object I have to add the namespace as a layer.  (i.e. myNamespace.myClass MyClass = new myNamespace.myClass();)  I know I could just use a using statement just was wondering if any problems occur by eliminating this noise.

Comment: That is not an "abstraction layer," and in fact it's not really any kind of layer. Really it's a... well, namespace. A container for names. It's important to use the correct terms when discussing these kinds of things. Anyway, `using` statements are not noise. If you think that eliminating `using` statements is a net bonus, you are in for a world of pain when a type name in your project clashes with a type name in a library you are using.

Comment: You don't want to end up like the poor sod in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324596/use-static-type-instead-of-variable

Comment: Meta-comment regarding the close votes: IMHO there are far too few questions on SO these days that inspire critical thought about, or question, generally accepted programming practices. SO used to be much more interesting when these still appeared more often. Now one is coming along and close to getting closed. Sad, that.

Comment: @stakx: that's what [programmers.se] is for.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I'm aware of Programmers. I've always found this an unfortunate split: SO gets the crowd, Programmers gets the interesting questions. (Of course that's just *my* subjective opinion, and somewhat over-simplified.)

Answer (score 9):

Namespaces have two principle uses:

First, they enable *the consumers of your code* to more easily understand, find and correctly use your code. There is a reason why the system diagnostic tools are in `System.Diagnostics` namespace. It's so that customers can know what the stuff in there is for.

Second, they are a mechanism for preventing name conflicts.

The first is actually by far the more important. Conflicts aren't *that* common. Still, they are possible and judicious use of namespaces prevents them.

If you don't care about your customers finding, understanding and using your code, and you don't have naming conflicts, then sure, skip using namespaces.

Answer (score 5):

> It creates layers that I am trying to avoid.

There are no real additional "layers" created.  The namespaces purely allow a way for the types to be organized, and help prevent naming collisions as projects get larger and more libraries are used.

As far as the runtime is concerned, there are no namespaces - all types are fully qualified, and the namespace in C# just changes the type name.  Leaving the namespace off just makes your type name more likely to conflict with other names, but will have no "real impact" on whether or not the code works, provided you don't use the same name more than once in your project, or use a name that's the same as a name of a type from a referenced assembly and imported via `using`.

---

Edit in response to comment:

> What I mean by "it creates layers" is that when I create the object I have to add the namespace as a layer. (i.e. myNamespace.myClass MyClass = new myNamespace.myClass();) "

Note that this is only required if you don't have a `using myNamespace;` statement, or if you use multiple namespaces within the project.  If you're always working within the project's default namespace, then you will not need to qualify the name.

Comment: *"provided you don't use the same name more than once in your project"* -- And that you don't use the same name as any type in any library namespace that you have imported with `using`, otherwise type names become ambiguous.

Comment: @cdhowie Yes, unless they're qualified using the global namespace qualifier operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx

Comment: Of course. That disambiguates the name. I'm referring specifically to unqualified type names, which is what most people use when developing in C#.

Comment: @cdhowie Yeah - I added a mention to that in my post (after your original comment)

Answer (score 3):

It might be a good idea to compare what life without namespaces looks like.  The C language does not support namespaces.  And very early in its existence, the open() function was used to open files.

Which means that no C programmer may *ever* use the name "open" for their own function.

Painful isn't it?

Namespaces help you use short and descriptive names.  They do not add layers, they only create longer names.  That you can very easily write shorter, the *using* directive makes it easy.

Comment: Very insightful as I can now see the pain I would be inflicting on myself in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can end up with conflicts and isn't standard practice for C#.  It won't truly hurt anything in the long run.

A conflict could arise if you named your class the same thing as another visible class.  For instance, if you named your class `Math` and had a `using System;` using statement, there would be a conflict that would only be resolved by specifying `System.Math`.

Again, not the norm and not something that should be published outside of internal use, but it sounds like you already know that :)

Comment: This is basically the only right to-the-point answer.  I like to answer this question with another: "why do we put files in directories instead of putting everything at the root of a volume?"  The answer is the same.

Comment: Could you expand on conflicts?  What would conflict and with whom?  I realize this is not standard practice.  Just call me a rebel :)

Comment: -1 because you're making claims without backing them up. 1. Why would this lead to conflicts, and why would these conflicts *in general* not exist when using namespaces? 2. Why won't it hurt? Why, and how, would not using namespaces "hurt"? I'd welcome a little elaboration on these points.

Comment: Regarding conflicts, namespaces help avoiding them, but do not make them impossible: Nothing stops us from declaring a `System.Math` type! That is, we must still choose a combination of namespace name and type name that won't conflict with anything declared elsewhere. If you decide not to use namespaces, the problem remains exactly the same: You must choose a name that won't conflict with anything declared elsewhere. Namespaces only appear to solve this problem, when it fact the solution is convention: User code should stay away from the BCL namespaces (`System` etc.).